# Xamarin Forms: WhenActivated not being fired reactiveui for viewmodel

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I can't understand why the WhenActivated func is not fired for a Xamarin Forms application.  The application has a LoginViewModel and a LoginView

- LoginView: inherits from ContentPageBase which itself derives from  : ContentPage, IViewFor which I think is expected
- LoginViewModel: ReactiveObject, IRoutableViewModel, ISupportsActivation

Here's the sample application code.

The first view LoginView is loaded as expected.  However, I would ideally like to load services and setup bindings in the WhenActivated func but it is not firing. See the LoginViewModel.

Any ideas?

[Source code](https://github.com/spacelinx/learn-reactiveui)

thanks

Comment: I just checked your repo and everything looks right, my ViewModelBase is very similar, I think your problema can be related to the fact you're using Autofac instead og Splat, may be

Comment: Thx for your comment. Why would not using Splat be a problem? Can you explain so I check?

Comment: Adrián,
 
Have a look this my branch https://github.com/spacelinx/learn-reactiveui/tree/with-splat/src/Learn 

I've removed autofac now completely, but WhenActivated still isn't being triggered. Any ideas?

Comment: Let me take a look,

Comment: ossentoo, I just loked your repo, and added a line in your Login.xaml.cs, this.WhenActivated(new Action<CompositeDisposable>(c =>{ /*Some dummy code*/ }));  and just worked !

Comment: In short, I understand that if you wnat to use WhenActivated in you ViewModel, you must use WhenActivated on your View

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok ossentoo, I'm not sure why but seems like if you want to use *WhenActivated* on your viewmodel you *must* use when activated on your view, the bindings are placed on view's code behind. Here is a little example:

```
public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase /*IRoutableViewModel, ISupportsActivation etc*/
{

    this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ViewModel activated.").DisposeWith(disposables);
        });

}
```

On the view:

```
public partial class LoginView : ContentPageBase<LoginViewModel>
{
    public LoginView()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        this.WhenActivated(new Action<CompositeDisposable>(c =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("From View ! (When Activated)");

          /*instead of xaml bindings you can use ReactiveUI bindings*/
           this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.UserName,
                v => v.UserName.Text).DisposeWith(disposables);
            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Password,
                v => v.Password.Text).DisposeWith(disposables);
        }));
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helped you. :)

Comment: Aha, I see what you are saying Adrián, well spotted :-).  Essentially, there's a code behind component to ReactiveUI that I had not appreciated!  For my own interest, does it mention that in documentation anywhere?  I couldn't find that. Anyway, let me try to make the change in a few hours and comeback to you.

Comment: I don't find it neither, but I'm pretty sure I readed somewhere :)

Comment: I found it: https://reactiveui.net/api/reactiveui/viewmodelactivator/
from the page: _NOTE: You **must** set up Activation in the corresponding View when using ViewModel Activation._

Comment: great  Adrián!  Confirmed that the break point is now hit.  thanks very much for your help.  Marked as the answer.